# Check either the generator awaiting "send" or yielding the value

Tags: python, generator

How can I check if the some blackbox generator is awaiting the value or it is returning the value now? I mean managing the following generator:

```
def gen():
  a = yield
  yield a
  yield a+1
  yield a+2
```

can be the following:

```
g = gen()
g.next()
print g.send(5)
print g.next()
print g.next()
```

and for the different generator, for example:

```
def gen():
  a = yield
  b = yield
  yield a+b
```

it needs to be different also, for example:

```
g = gen()
g.next()
g.send(1)
print g.send(2)
```

So the question is how can I choose between sending value in generator and getting results from it only in case of blackbox (third-party) generator? I need to write the following code:

```
values = [1, 2, 3]
results = list()
g = gen()
g.next()
for v in values:
  # needs this magic
  if g.__awaits__:  # in case of "x = yield" expression
    results.append(g.send(v))
  elif g.__yields__:  # in case of "yield x" expression
    results.append(g.next())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because there isn't any difference in terms of the allowable operations on those two "kinds" of generators.  You can always send a value to the generator as soon as you have called `next` on it once, even if the generator doesn't do anything with the sent value:

```
>>> def gen():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...     yield 3
>>> x = gen()
>>> next(x)
1
>>> x.send('hello')
2
>>> x.send('hello')
3
```

There's no way to tell whether the generator "needs" you to send a value except by reading the documentation for whatever generator you're using.